# How to pass tuples (not array) as WHERE constraint parameters in SQL query via client library (Postgres)?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have empirically discovered that PostgreSQL lets you create 'tuples' (terminology mine, I don't know what they call it) to define a multi-column condition in WHERE:

```
update T set x=true where (a_id, b_id) IN ((3428, 3544), (3450, 3542));
```

This seems to do exactly what I hope it would do: `x` is updated where a_id = first item in tuple AND b_id = second item in tuple. This is close to being useful, but for it to really matter, I have to be able to set these 'tuples' as parameters from a client library; in particular, `node-pg` in this case.

Is it possible to bind $1 to something in the following query , such that $1 is a list of 0 or more pairs of `a_id` and `b_id`?

```
client.query("UPDATE t SET x=true WHERE (a_id, b_id) IN $1"), [...?])
```

If not, can I at least do

```
client.query("UPDATE t SET x=true WHERE (a_id, b_id) IN ($1, $2, ...$N)", [ a1b1, a1b2, ...aNbN ])
```

?

Comment: You can do the second, but not the first.

Comment: Best advise: Avoid tuples like a plague, they are a legacy stuff that was superseded by JSON/JSONB - is what you should be using instead.

Comment: @vitaly-t JSON/JSONB with regards to SQL query? Can you point to some documentation on the topic?

Answer (score 0):

below is a way to pass array of integers with one argument to unnamed prepared statement, but I'm sure how much this is usable, but surely doable with node-postgres.

sql:

```
f=# create table nu(i int, t text);
CREATE TABLE
f=# insert into nu values (1,'a'),(2,'a'),(4,'a');
INSERT 0 3
f=# select * from nu;
 i | t
---+---
 1 | a
 2 | a
 4 | a
(3 rows)
```

js:

```
client.query("update nu set t = 'b' where i = any ($1::int[]) returning *", [[1,2,3]], (err, res) => {
  console.log(err, res.rows)
  client.end()
})
```

output:

```
null [ anonymous { i: 1, t: 'b' }, anonymous { i: 2, t: 'b' } ]
```

extra check:

```
f=# select * from nu;
 i | t
---+---
 4 | a
 1 | b
 2 | b
(3 rows)
```

Regarding the second way - it's done exactly as you show in your example

**UPDATE**

Due to my inacurate reading I answered different question again. yet I decided to leave above, so the next bit of code would be more comprehendable:

```
client.query("update nu set t = 'foo' where (i,t)::text = any ($1::text[]) returning *", ['{"(1,b)","(2,b)"}'], (err, res) => {
  console.log(err, res.row)
  client.end()
})
```

and thus statement produced:

```
t 2017-10-26 07:53:25 UTC :: LOG:  execute <unnamed>: update nu set t = 'foo' where (i,t)::text = any ($1::text[]) returning *
t 2017-10-26 07:53:25 UTC :: DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '{"(1,b)","(2,b)"}'
```

and result:

```
f=# select * from nu;
 i |  t
---+-----
 4 | a
 1 | foo
 2 | foo
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Sure; actually, I remembered `ANY` too. But it's only useful if I can pass parameters so I can actually write the query with `WHERE (a_id, b_id) = ANY ($1)`. The question is, if $1 is an array, what are the elements that will be parsed by Pg as (a_id, b_id) pairs? Seems like 2-element subarrays don't work, thus this particular way of writing the query with parameters in mind is useless. Basically, have to do `WHERE (a_id=$1 AND b_id=$2) OR (a_id=$3 AND b_id=$4) OR....`

Comment: @user3175580 I updated the answer - 
hopefully now I understand the OP and answering the right question :)